# Puppet: how to install package httpd only on specific nodes/ip?

Tags: puppet

Suppose 10 servers,but I want to install httpd only on two servers and OS must be Centos,I have tried with this manifest

```
class apache {
        if $::operatingsystem == 'CentOS' {
                package { "httpd":
                        ensure => latest
                }
        }
}
node '10.2.0.5' {
        include apache
}

node '10.2.0.6' {
        include apache
}
```

But apply catalog fail.
I have tried to replace apache with httpd..but no success.

Comment: You cannot mix a site manifest and a class manifest together. Try finding a basic Puppet development tutorial to assist with your coding, as this is something that would be addressed there..

Comment: It's worth noting that one *used* to be able to include class and node declarations in the same manifest, @MattSchuchard.  I'm uncertain when exactly that changed, and even now [the language reference](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.0/lang_visual_index.html) only says where each kind of declaration *should* go, not where it *must* go.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I thought it was valid up through the end of Puppet3, but now you have me second-guessing myself. I guess the next question is whether this manifest is in a site manifest, or a class manifest.

Comment: Searching on net i cannot find a manifest (class or site) to update only some nodes. I know how to install on all nodes,but not only on some nodes,my question was about this.

Comment: @elbarna, either you are not looking hard enough or you do not recognize what you're looking for when you see it.  It is absolutely routine to manage different machines to have different configuration.  This can be done in many ways, but using conditionals, as in your example, is one.  Generally, though, instead of declaring class `apache` on every node and making it a do-nothing on some, the preferred approach is usually to declare that class only on those nodes where you want apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, I had to declare a class called testmodule(name can be random) and select package for specific hosts,for other hosts I put nothing for now but I can select other actions.
Tested and works perfect.

```
class testmodule {
package { ['telnet', 'glusterfs', 'wget']:
ensure => installed,
}
}

node 'node1.mysite.example', 'node2.mysite.example' {
  include testmodule
}

node 'default' {
}
```